# resizing large formulas with `exams2moodle`

Tags: r, moodle, mathjax, r-exams

I am using `exams2moodle` to prepare exams for my students (and I appreciate it a lot!)

I sometimes use large formulas. What is the best way to resize them?

Comment: Do you want smaller fonts?

Comment: The best thing would be resizing everything in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Moodle, mathematical LaTeX equations are rendered with the MathJax plugin (https://www.MathJax.org/). This is quite powerful and also allows viewers to adjust the font size in their browsers. Specifically, if you move the mouse over the equation and then right-click, you get a MathJax context menu. In this you can select > Math Settings > Zoom Factor > ... and then you can adjust the font size as needed. See also the screenshot below.

More details on mathematical equations using R/exams and MathJax, see: http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/math/.

[image: moodle-mathjax]